# @Pattern for alphanumeric string - Bean validation

Tags: java, regex, annotations, bean-validation

I have a variable name in a bean. I want to add `@Pattern` validation to accept only alphanumeric.

Currently, I have this one.

```
 @NotNull
 @Pattern(regexp = "{A-Za-z0-9}*")
 String name;
```

But the error is `Invalid regular expression.`
I tried `[A-Za-z0-9]`. But this is not working either. No errors though. It shows any valid input as failed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Do you try this pattern: `^[A-Za-z0-9]*$`

or `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$` to avoid empty results.

If you want to check that a string contains only specific characters, you must add anchors (`^` for beginning of the string, `$` for end of the string) to be sure that your pattern matches the whole string.

Curly brackets are only used to express a repetition, example: if I want two `a`:
 `a{2}`
You can't put letters inside. The only situation where you can find letters enclosed between curly brackets is when you use UNICODE character classes: `\p{L}` (`L` for Letters), `\p{Greek}`, `\p{Arabian}`, ...

Comment: I added `[A-Za-z0-9]+$` in my dna spec file and that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

In addition, you may use a character class, which can be used in curly braces, namely Alnum. For example, for an alphanumeric character having length between 1 and 32 characters inclusive:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{Alnum}]{1,32}$")
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: This is as per specification but doesnt work.

@Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{Alnum}]$")

Comment: @Dinesh, I think you were expecting it to validate a mandatory Alphanumeric. In other words, you expected this to block only alphabets or only numbers. That's not the intended behaviour. It allows only alphabets, only numbers and alphanumeric strings.