# Java validation add constraint for only set of string values

Tags: java, validation

Using **java** validation is it possible to add constrains for a string property like it should have only some set of values. `(for ex : AA,BB,CC,DD)`. I know I can use something like below, but it does not stop some junk values apart from my expected values.

The below **code**, allow me `junk/unexpected` values

```
@Size(min=2, max=2,message="")
@pattern("regex patter to allow string only)
private String prop;
```

Comment: For a set of values with defined possible values, use an `enum`

Comment: Whose implementation of the Bean Validation API are you using? Hibernate?

Comment: validation-api-2.0.1-Final

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481029/pattern-for-alphanumeric-string-bean-validation

Comment: No, it was accepting all a-z string

Comment: What have you tried and can you give an example of "junk values" that slip through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Pattern(regexp = "word1|word2|word3")
String name;
```

If you need more elaborated regexp use the one you need in the usual way.